# What tests might someone do to assess possible brain damage from time travel?

Tags: science-based, time-travel, brain, spacetime-dimensions, medical

I have a character who travels in time, but after making major jumps (like 100 years forward), she begins experiencing side effects—first nose bleeds, but the symptoms begin to increase to things like seizures.

What tests might someone run that would prove the seizures were linked to time travel? (I’m thinking along the lines of J J Abrams’s “Fringe.”) Could there be some kind of treatment that would lessen the effects?

Comment: How does the time travel cause problems? We can design tests if you can say how the time travel is affecting the body. Without that info, I’m not sure how to help.

Comment: @srm not sure if this is what you’re asking, but it causes nosebleeds, seizures, nausea, and headaches. It’s a result of a human being existing in a dimension of time they shouldn’t exist in (for example, their matter leaving one point on the timeline and occupying a different one they didn’t exist in previously—or are already existing in). I imagine it as the atoms in their body rejecting their place on the timeline, if that makes sense.

Comment: What you've described are symptoms of a condition that you tell us about in science-fiction terms. To answer, we'd need to know the organic origin of those symptoms - that's not something we can know from the description, only guess at. Without knowing the damage caused we can't tell you how to go about detecting it.

Comment: Like, does your transmission process move one cell at a time and so introduce splits in the cellular clocks? Or does the transmission process create internal pressure on organs that might create small air pockets that shouldn't normally be there? How does your time travel process affect space/matter? You answer that, then we can apply it to biology.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that merely existing in a time other than that from which the subject originated would cause problems. It is far more likely that any problems would be caused by the act of time travel itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In general

"What tests might someone run that would prove the seizures were linked to time travel?" -- get two cohorts of test subjects (laboratory animals), one of which is the control. Subject one cohort to repeated time travels, and have tests run on both cohorts by someone else (subjects could be numbered, their number assigned randomly to either cohort).

Depending on the animal there are several standard cognitive tests. Periodically, some subjects would be terminated and autopsied to assess any organic changes.

Another, more animal-friendly possibility would be to subject to the same treatment biological cultures, very pure crystals, known isotope references and sample solutions; then perform analyses on them. A change in the number of lattice defects in a crystal could indicate that some low-level atomic disruption is taking place. A silver halide solution testing positive for metallic silver could indicate the presence of high-energy particles through the sample during time-travel; a variation in isotope decay might indicate a significant variation in neutrino flux, which in turn might interfere with ordinary matter through reverse beta decay. All these phenomena have the potential of negatively impacting with biologic processes.

## In a single individual

Here things get very difficult, because we would need a precise baseline and cannot readily use statistical analysis. Also, destructive testing (e.g. an autopsy) is unavailable.

The first hurdle is to determine neural damage and its extent. Cognitive tests, fMRI scan and PET metabolic analysis can pinpoint certain types of brain damage. Conduction tests and evoked potentials test can assess damage at the nerve level (e.g. demyelinization). Specific immunoassays (ran on blood and spinal liquor) might help determine whether any among several kinds of cellular degradation is present (for example, micro-traumas to the brain's small blood vessels).

More exotic exams - for example a Doppler fluxometry of the brachial plexus area *might* help determine if blood circulation is being impacted in any way, on the premise that whatever is influencing the blood vessels must do so to *all* blood vessels, and while this examination is impossible on the brain itself, it can be run in other areas.

Repeating the tests after each time travel, or immediately before and immediately after, might yield some clues (for example, a sudden increase in blood pressure would explain most of the observed symptoms).

Once determined the damage *and the mechanism of the damage*, something can probably be done (even if my first suggestion would be *stop time traveling, you're killing yourself!*). If the problem is caused by high-energy particles from outside the time capsule (rather than "virtual" particles generated equally throughout its volume) then the answer might be *shielding*. Blood pressure can be controlled. Some kinds of traumas can be maybe avoided using a special suit or traveling while submerged in water or oil or some rheological fluids. Or it might be that traveling under light anesthesia is enough.

If the damage is not cumulative, then a sufficient rest time between travels would solve most problems.

All in all, I believe you have a wide range of possibilities - however you wish this thing to go, there almost surely is a mechanism to explain *why* it must be so.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach to prove causal link between A and B is to make a [double blind experiment](https://www.infobloom.com/what-is-a-double-blind-test.htm):

> A double blind test is a scientific test in which neither test subjects nor administrators know who is in the control group and who is in the experimental group. The intent is to create an unbiased test environment, ensuring that the results of the testing are accurate and will stand up to analysis by other members of the scientific community. The concept of a double blind test is an excellent example of the scientific method, since it aims to be entirely objective and potentially repeatable.
>
> To administer a double blind test, a separate coordinator assigns the test subjects random numbers and divides them into two groups. Each subject is given a unique code which is known only to the coordinator. This coordinator also provides the drug to be administered. At the end of the trial, the researchers are given the code so that they can begin to interpret the results.
>
> Using a double blind test method can ensure that test results are valid and more widely accepted by the general scientific community. It tends to cost more to administer a double blind test, because of additional paperwork and processing, but many scientists feel that this cost is well worth the benefits. In an even more elaborate situation, a triple blind test, the statistician examining the results is also kept in the dark about the identities of experimental and control group members.

This is about proving that time travel causes the damages you list. The mechanism involved in causing the damage will also influence the related treatment, but with no information on that, it's an unanswerable question.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that could be done is prior to any time travel a baseline "health assessment" is conducted to establish the condition the person is in prior to undergoing any time travel. This could be thought of as being similar to pre-employment medical examination that can be used later to establish whether a deleterious change in a person was the result of conditions of employment.

For your time traveler, tests that could be done include:

- a general physical medical examination
- a series of blood tests, particularly for changes in white & red blood cells
- [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CT_scan) scans of the brain and torso
- For imaging of soft tissue concerns, particular for the brain [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging)
  scan would be essential, as proven during investigations of [Havana Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havana_syndrome)
- Psychological appraisals would also be necessary

Answer (score 1):

**What tests might someone run that would prove the seizures were linked to time travel?**

Take a large number of animals (test subjects). For example lab rats. Keep half of them (the control animals) in the lab. Send the others on trips through time. Afterwards keep both groups of animals in identical labs. Observe the differences in behaviour between the time travelers and control animals. In particular the time travelers have loads more seizures and nosebleeds. This establishes an empirical link between the cause and effects.

**Could there be some kind of treatment that would lessen the effects?**

Yes. The exact form of the treatment will depend on the exact mechanism of how time travel causes seizures. That is worth a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 questions here.**

First the easy one.  Is there treatment?  The 2 symptoms you give are nosebleeds and seizures.  There are not many diseases that cause both.  A cancer up in the sinuses that infiltrates the brain could cause both but that is kind of a show stopper.  A better disease is TTP: thrombotic thrombogenic purpura.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrombotic_thrombocytopenic_purpura

> The signs and symptoms of TTP may at first be subtle and nonspecific.
> Many people experience an influenza-like or diarrheal illness before
> developing TTP.[7] Neurological symptoms are very common and vary
> greatly in severity. Frequently reported symptoms include feeling very
> tired, confusion, and headaches.[7] Seizures and symptoms similar to
> those of a stroke can also be seen.[7] Other symptoms include, but are
> not limited to jaundice or paleness of the skin, a fast heart rate or
> shortness of breath, or pinpoint-sized purple or reddish dots on the
> skin known as petechiae.[citation needed]
>
> As TTP progresses, blood clots form within small blood vessels
> (microvasculature), and platelets (clotting cells) are consumed. As a
> result, bruising, and rarely bleeding can occur. The bruising often
> takes the form of purpura, while the most common site of bleeding, if
> it occurs, is from the nose or gums.

TTP is a good one because it is rare, protean in its manifestations and can be triggered by a lot of different things.  Immunosuppression is the traditional treatment.  Plasma exchange is an effective treatment.  There are going to be specific treatments in the future and your time traveler should go there and get one.

---

The other question is proving time travel is associated.  That is hard.   Maybe TTP just happened to her and was not related to time travel.  The two ways I can think of are if the severity of her symptoms (and severity of TTP can be measured with blood tests) is related to the distance she jumps, and over time and living with TTP she figures it out.  A good symptom for this would be aphasia which can affect people with TTP and would not be tough for you to depict in prose - she struggles finding words and comes up with the wrong one.  She knows it is wrong when she hears it.   You would need a waxing and waning disease course of TTP for this which is unusual but not impossible.

The other method  would be if there are other time jumpers and TTP was already a known issue with them.  It is like TTP being associated with a given medicine - the first time it might have been coincidence but as additional people develop TTP after the same medicine the association will become more clear.